# Permission denied when running NPM module that sets environment variables in Nodejs on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to set environment variables on process.env in nodejs using the npm module env-cmd. My system is running Kubuntu 18.04.

I consistently get "permission denied" even when using sudo.

My node and npm versions are the ones from the Ubuntu package manager. So not the latest, but the latest "approved" ones.

I would like to get past this permission denied thing.

I have tried updating env-cmd to the latest package and using the -f switch with the exact same results. I have verified my file path is correct and double checked my code. Which leads me to think this is a "linux thing"

from **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
```

from **dev.env**

`PORT=3000`

from **index.js**

`const port = process.env.PORT;`

The expected result is that node runs and variables get set on process.env

**Terminal output is**

```
hoo@BadWolf:~/storage/node-task-api v3$ npm run dev

> node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev /home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3
> sudo env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js

[sudo] password for hoo: 
sudo: env-cmd: command not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev: `sudo env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev script 'sudo env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js'.
....(details on how to report an issue)
npm ERR!     /home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3/npm-debug.log
```

**debug.log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~predev: node-task-manager@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~predev: no script for predev, continuing
7 info lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: node-task-manager@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3
11 silly lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
13 info lifecycle node-task-manager@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
14 verbose stack Error: node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev: `env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 126
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
15 verbose pkgid node-task-manager@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3
17 error Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
19 error node v8.10.0
20 error npm  v3.5.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev: `env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the node-task-manager@1.0.0 dev script 'env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-task-manager package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js
....(details on how to report an issue)
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with some help from Adam Hartleb, a Course Assistant at Udemy. He suggested running it with npx, which worked, after some finagling.

For anyone else having this problem, here is what I did:

I solved this by inspecting the source code for env-cmd, then re-reading the docs.

The problem  is that, in Ubuntu 18.04 at least, env-cmd doesn't play well with non-default file locations.

To get it to run, you must have a version of Node that supports npx. If you are in Ubuntu then you have to use a version of node that is not supported by Canonical. The way I solved that was to install NVM and Node 10.15.3

[how to install NVM and Node LTS](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-latest-node-js-and-nmp-on-ubuntu)

You will need to use the default file location for your .env file:

```
 ./.env
```

You will need to remove any references to non-default file locations,as their presence will only anger env-cmd. It will have a literal hangup. (it will actually spawn an error called "hangup"). It will also use the word "spawn". I only tell you what I saw.

I changed my "dev" script to

```
"dev" : "npx env-cmd nodemon src/index.js"
```

It should work now. May the .env-gods be merciful upon your app.

**BACKSTORY: How I got there**

Adam's suggestion of "npx env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js" resulted in:

```
hoo@BadWolf:~/storage/node-task-api v3$ npx env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js
(node:19209) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to locate env file at default location (./.env)
    at /home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3/node_modules/env-cmd/dist/get-env-vars.js:47:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/home/hoo/storage/node-task-api v3/node_modules/env-cmd/dist/get-env-vars.js:5:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at findNodeScript.then.existing (/home/hoo/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpx/index.js:268:14)
(node:19209) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:19209) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I traced the problem back to a few undefined variables in the module code, which I logged to terminal.

```
hoo@BadWolf:~/storage/node-task-api v3$ npx env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js
Russ logging from get-env-vars.js 27:  getEnvFile({ filePath, fallback }): filePath = undefined
Russ logging from get-env-vars.js 27: getEnvFile({ filePath, fallback }): fallback = undefined
```

Creating a .env file at ./.env and running the same npx script (with the non-default file argument)

```
hoo@BadWolf:~/storage/node-task-api v3$ npx env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js
spawn ./config/dev.env EACCES
Hangup
```

With the non-default file location removed, to spin up the server with env-cmd run:

```
npx env-cmd  nodemon src/index.js
```

Comment: FYI...the -f command worked like a charm for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Appears your are in same course. Command 'env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env node src/index.js' and env-cmd version I am using is env-cmd@9.0.3